# Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`

Tags: reactjs, setstate

[While I'm trying to reload in login or registration page it just gives me this following kind error but while taking in cloud this error leave, is this happen only in localHost case or something?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZtav.png)

Comment: add your code, or try to send it in code sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning was introduced since React V16

If you are using functional components you could wrap the setState call into useEffect.

```
// example
useEffect(() => {
// here
 },[]);
```